# Is there a way to trigger the event viewDidUnload?

Tags: iphone

I hope manually trigger the event viewDidUnload (unload an viewcontroller).
Is it possible?

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's a possibility to trigger this method, because it's only called when memory is getting low. Why don't you use viewDidDisappear: or viewWillDisappear: ?

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear:

Answer (score 0):

Just allocate lots and lots of big objects. It's bound to be called sooner rather than later, as soon as your device memory starts running low.